# How to change privatemsg message participants

Tags: privatemsg

I am using [private message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) drupal module.In my project there are many roles and these role type user can send message to another user.In default If user A send message to user B ,and user B is logged in then under read message tab there is a message label "Between you and email id of user A". similarly 
for other user also.But my requirement is that message label should be as 
"Between you and admin mail id" not mail id of that user who send this message.
[image]

Comment: read this https://www.drupal.org/node/702934

Comment: i must admit I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. "Between you and email id for sender." is not even a proper English sentence, I'm afraid. Please rephrase it, keeping in mind that: 1) Most of people here are not native speakers and 2) You know what you mean. We only know what we can understand from what you write.